# Variable batch_size in call function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement an attention network with TensorFlow 2. Thus, for every image, I want to take only some glimpses, i.e. a small part from the image. For this I have implemented a subclass from tensorflow.keras.models.Model, here is a snippet out of it.

```
class RecurrentAttentionModel(models.Model):
# ...

def call(self, inputs):

    l = tf.random.uniform((40,2,), minval=0, maxval=1)

    for _ in range(0, self.glimpses):
        glimpse = tf.image.extract_glimpse(inputs, size=(self.retina_size, self.retina_size), offsets=l, centered=False, normalized=True)

        # some other code...
        # update l to take a glimpse somewhere else


    return result
```

Now, the code above works and trains perfectly, but my issue is, that I have the hardcoded 40 in it, the batch_size which I have defined in my dataset. I am not able to read/get the batch_size in the call method since the variable "inputs" is of the form `Tensor("input_1_77:0", shape=(None, 250, 500, 1), dtype=float32)` where the `None` for the batch_size seems to be expected behavior.
When I just initialize l with the following code (without the batch_size)

```
l = tf.random.uniform((2,), minval=0, maxval=1)
```

it throws this error

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'recurrent_attention_model_86/ExtractGlimpse' (op: 'ExtractGlimpse') with input shapes: [?,250,500,1], [2], [2]
```

what I totally understand but I have no idea how I could implement the initial values according to the batch_size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the batch size dimension dynamically by using `tf.shape`.

```
l = tf.random.normal(tf.stack([tf.shape(inputs)[0], 2]), minval=0, maxval=1))
```